# Elasticsearch - Nest - 'Range' query on 'string'

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Can you do a `range` query on a `string` still using `nest` in the lastest 2.0 alpha release? Or has this been dropped in elasticsearch.

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html) -- suggests it is still in Elasticsearch itself

however

[Range](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/82c938893b2ff4ddca03a8e977ad14a16da712ba/src/Nest/CommonOptions/Range/Range.cs) -- seems to only accept 'double'.

E.g.

```
...
(sh => sh.Range(ra => ra.Field(of =>
    of.Name).LessThanOrEquals(
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textInputName)
            ? textInputName.ToString(): null
    ))
...
```

Used to work in 1.7 Nest, but now says the input for `LessThanOrEquals` must be a `double`.

How do I now get everything where 'name' is between, for example, 'a' and 'f'?

**Edit**:

I think it was removed [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/commit/a65a3ff62631883f5a76652ccf4ad03d50e891e2) in file `src/Nest/QueryDsl/TermLevel/Range/RangeQuery.cs`... just can not find 'why'.... :S

Comment: The related issue was https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1611 but it doesn't really mention why either.

Comment: Thank you for raising this, it looks like this was removed by accident. I have opened an issue for it https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1728. The `Range()` method works on numeric fields with a `DateRange()` method to work on date fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range queries on string fields are now in [the alpha2 release on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/2.0.0-alpha2)

```
(sh => sh
    .TermRange(ra => ra
        .Field(of => of.Name)
        .LessThanOrEquals(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textInputName)
            ? textInputName.ToString()
            : null)
)
```